# How to 'sudo' without 'newgrp'

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, sudo, sudoers, visudo

I have two CentOS 6.8 servers running on VirtualBoxes.

On one, I can login as a regular user then use "sudo" to run administrator commands. I just add "sudo" to the front and all works as expected.

On the other, I need to first run "newgrp wheel", otherwise it nags me that I'm not in the sudoers file. Once that's done, all is well.

As far as I can tell, both systems are otherwise identical. The username in both cases has a primary group of "users" and is also a member of "wheel" and "apache" groups. The "wheel" group, of course, has been given "ALL" access via "visudo".

The only difference, if it's important, is that the first one is a VM on Linux, and I access it via Putty. The nagging one is a VM on Windows, and I access it via the VirutalBox screen.

It's not a very big issue, but I *like* not needing the extra step. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: If you want to vote down my question, I'd appreciate an explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out the systems were not as identical as I thought. The "visudo" sudoers file on the nagging version had somehow been restored to its original version, which meant that the "%wheel" directive was commented out. I only discovered that in trying to add a 10 minute timeout.